# Почему происходит ошибка? я не понимаю

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

При вызове функции которая отвечает за запись данных в базу данных, происходит неизвестная мне ошибка. почему она происходит и как решить проблему?

**код**

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(Text(startswith='read '))
async def process_callback_button1(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    for ID in await read_ID():
        list_ID = []
        ID = str(ID)
        ID = int(re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]',r'', ID))
        list_ID.append(ID)
        if callback.from_user.id in list_ID:
            await callback.answer(f'вы уже зарегистрированы', show_alert=True)
            break
        elif callback.from_user.id not in list_ID:
            await add_ID(callback.from_user.id)
            await callback.answer(f'User ВЫ зарегестрированы', show_alert=True)
        else:
            await callback.answer('Непредвиденная ошибка')



@dp.message_handler(commands=['Регистрирование'])
async def register(message:types.Message):
    await message.answer('нажмите на кнопку ниже\/', reply_markup= InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(InlineKeyboardButton('Регистрация', callback_data=f'read ')))
```

**ошибка**

*aiogram.utils.exceptions.InvalidQueryID: Query is too old and response timeout expired or query id is invalid*

**база данных**

```
import sqlite3 as sq

def sql_start2():
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('Waurma_client_id.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('Data base #2 connected OK')

    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list_id (id TEXT)')
    base.commit()

async def add_ID(args):
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO list_id VALUES (?)', (args,))
    base.commit()

async def read_ID():
    return cur.execute('SELECT * FROM list_id').fetchall()
```